# PUT Method in action and reducer in Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have created an UPDATE_ITEM type but how to code it in here I don't have the idea since I want to update it by its ID. Also I want to dipatch this action with the reducer itemReducer.js which I have given in the code below. Can someone please help me with the code?//itemAction.js Action. The get, delete and add routes is working but this put method is giving me headache.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { GET_ITEMS, ADD_ITEM, DELETE_ITEM, UPDATE_ITEM, ITEMS_LOADING } from'./types';

export const getItems = () => dispatch => {
  dispatch(setItemsLoading());

  axios.get('/api/items').then(res =>
    dispatch({
      type: GET_ITEMS,
      payload: res.data
    })
  );
};

export const addItem = item => dispatch => {
  axios.post('/api/items', item).then(res =>
    dispatch({
      payload: res.data
    })
  );
};

 //UPDATE_ITEM Action Here

export const deleteItem = id => dispatch => {
  axios.delete(`/api/items/${id}`).then(res =>
    dispatch({
      type: DELETE_ITEM,
      payload: id
    })
  );
};

export const setItemsLoading = () => {
  return {
    type: ITEMS_LOADING
  };
};
```

This is the itemReducer which I also need help

```
import { GET_ITEMS, DELETE_ITEM, UPDATE_ITEM, ADD_ITEM, ITEMS_LOADING
} from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
  items: [],
  loading: false
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {

  case GET_ITEMS:
    return {
      ...state,
      items: action.payload,
      loading: false
    };

  case DELETE_ITEM:
    return {
      ...state,
      items: state.items.filter(item => item._id !== action.payload)
    };

  //UPDATE_ITEM Reducer here

  case ADD_ITEM:
    return {
      ...state,
      items: [action.payload, ...state.items]
    };


  case ITEMS_LOADING:
    return {
      ...state,
      loading: true
    };

  default:
    return state;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess your update looks like the add:

```
//UPDATE_ITEM Action
export const updateItem = item => dispatch => {
  axios.put('/api/items', item).then(res =>
    dispatch({
      type:'UPDATE_ITEM',
      payload: res.data
    })
  );
};
```

In your reducer you can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
case UPDATE_ITEM:
    return {
      ...state,
      items: state.items.map(
        item => 
          item._id === action.payload.id
            //return action payload (modified item) instead of
            //  original item when item id is updated item id
            ? action.payload
            : item//ids not the same, return original item
      )
    };
```

Comment: can you be specific with your answer in the comments line that you have give and also here is my component.

Comment: @BakorKharkongor I thought you needed help with the action and reducer but looking at the jsx you posted you don't even have an action to get an item in edit mode and have the jsx show that item differently (in inputs) with an update button. Maybe you should try to add an edit button first that will set a state editId to be used to render the item in edit mode and show the update button.

Comment: I have finished creating one button for edit but just because of this actions and reducer I am stuck. Thats y i deleted the code for edit button in the ShoppingList component

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, ListGroup, ListGroupItem, Button } from 'reactstrap';
import { CSSTransition, TransitionGroup } from 'react-transition-group';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getItems, deleteItem, updateItem } from '../actions/itemActions';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class ShoppingList extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getItems();
  }

  onDeleteClick = id => {
    this.props.deleteItem(id);
  };


  render() {
    const { items } = this.props.item;
    return (
      <Container>
        <ListGroup>
          <TransitionGroup className="shopping-list">
            {items.map(({ _id, name, body }) => (
              <CSSTransition key={_id} timeout={500} classNames="fade">
                <ListGroupItem>
                  <Button
                    className="remove-btn"
                    color="danger"
                    size="sm"
                    onClick={this.onDeleteClick.bind(this, _id)}
                  >
                   DELETE
          </Button>

          {/*An update button will be called here*/}
          {/*<Button
                    className="update-btn"
                    color="success"
                    size="sm"
                  >
                  Update 
          </Button>*/}
          

    <div></div>
      <table className="rows">
      <thead>
      <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Body</td>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr>
      <td>{ name }</td>
      <td>{ body }</td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
      </table>
                </ListGroupItem>
              </CSSTransition>
            ))}
          </TransitionGroup>
        </ListGroup>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

ShoppingList.propTypes = {
  getItems: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  item: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  item: state.item
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { getItems, deleteItem }
)(ShoppingList);
```